# jquery search using contain not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jquery to search from static html page which contains  elements dynamically generated So far i have written this script.When i search it hide div that not contain but when i press backspace and with empty search text box the div elements don't come back

**CODE:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.searchtextbox').keyup(function(){
        searchedText = $('.searchtextbox').val();
        $(".grid:not(:contains('"+searchedText+"'))").hide();
        //I want here code to return back the div elements  
        //when i empty the text box using backpace.
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show all grid elements before hiding the ones you filter out. You should also check if there is a search string, otherwise it will hide everyone that doesn’t contains "", which would be all of them:

```
var $grid = $(".grid").show()
if( searchedText ) {
    $grid.filter(":not(:contains('"+searchedText+"'))").hide();
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply yes it works like example if i entered love and it showed up grid with love and when i press back with lov in text box it show all grid divs with lov but when i empty search textbox nothing show up but i want all grid divs